# General SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

This might be stupid, but databases are not my thing :) Imagine the following scenario. A user can create a post and other users can reply to his post, thus forming a thread. Everything goes in a single table called Posts. All the posts that form a thread are connected with each other through a generated key called ThreadID. This means that when user #1 creates a new post, a ThreadID is generated, and every reply that follows has a ThreadID pointing to the initial post (created by user #1). What I am trying to do is limit the number of replies to let's say 20 per thread. I'm wondering which of the approaches bellow is faster:

## 1

I add a new integer column (e.x. Counter) to Posts. After a user replies to the initial post, I update the initial post's Counter field. If it reaches 20 I lock the thread.

## 2

After a user replies to the initial post, I select all the posts that have the same ThreadID. If this collection has more than 20 items, I lock the thread.

For further information: I am using SQL Server database and Linq-to-SQL entity model.
I'd be glad if you tell me your opinions on the two approaches or share another, faster approach.

Best Regards,

Kiril

Answer (score 1):

Been there and have done variants of both solutions.

I personally don't like solution 1 because the counter column doesn't have any meaning for all the reply posts.

I usually end up with

### 3

Create **two tables**, one for the `Threads` (thread starters) and one for the `Posts` (thread replies).

Often you'll find that for a *Thread* there are more fields than for a *post*. For example, you could add a column `IsLocked` to the Threads table. You then won't have to remember the magic number (20) to know whether the *Thread* is locked or not.

I often also have a `Title` for the thread, but not for the posts. And sometimes another column to know whether the thread `IsSticky` or not. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 will be fine so long as you have an index on ThreadID.
Option 1 would also be fine (assuming you have an index on ThreadID), but the code would be more complex I think.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this *reply counter* is not part of a post, neither a thread. This is a system parameter which would fit into another data table. Let's call it SysParams, for the sake of this example.

```
CREATE TABLE SysParams (
    SpId int IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key
    , SpTableName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL -- To what table this parameter applies?
    , SpName nvarchar(10) NOT NULL  -- Parameter name
    , SpValue nvarchar(20) NOT NULL -- Value of the parameter
)

insert into SysParams (SpTableName, SpName, SpValue) values (N'Posts', N'MaxAnswersPerThread', N'20')
GO
```

Then, when loading your posts or threads, you're loading only once this parameter from the `SysParams` table and lock if the count of answers is equals to this parameter value.

> Why a *nvarchar(20)* for the *SpValue* field?

Because doing so, you might as well have some other parameters which would consist of string values.

As for getting these values, you shall code a *GetParameterValue()* function which would simply return the value of the *SpValue* field depending on the *SpTableName* and *SpName* specified on the function call. This way, you might as well have other parameters for the same table serving different purposes.